# How to link ntfs-3g with homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, ntfs-3g

Forgive me if this is elsewhere, but I can't find it.

I am trying to install NTFS-3G on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan).

[I am following the process at this link](https://gist.github.com/mrpatiwi/8bca2f20b140150f1cbd)

But the step to install NTFS-3G reports:

```
$ brew install homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g
Warning: homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g-2015.3.14 already installed, it's just not linked
```

So...

1. How do I *just* link the installed item?
2. Once that's done, how do I complete the install process? Is there anything that the 'brew install...' process would do after linking?

EDIT:
Following bfontaine... I get:

```
$ brew link homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g                                
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ntfs-3g/2015.3.14... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/ntfs-3g/README
Target /usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g/README
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g/README'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite ntfs-3g

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run ntfs-3g
$ brew link --overwrite homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ntfs-3g/2015.3.14... 
Error: Could not symlink share/doc/ntfs-3g/README
/usr/local/share/doc/ntfs-3g is not writable.
```

Am I going down a hole? If I brew uninstall, will it clean everything up, or do I have to manually clean it up?

This is getting messy...

EDIT2:
The output of brew link --overwrite --dry-run is:

```
$ brew link --overwrite --dry-run homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g
Would remove:
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/acls.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/attrib.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/attrlist.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/bitmap.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/bootsect.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/cache.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/collate.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/compat.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/compress.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/debug.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/device.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/device_io.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/dir.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/ea.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/efs.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/endians.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/index.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/inode.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/ioctl.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/layout.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/lcnalloc.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/logfile.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/logging.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/mft.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/misc.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/mst.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/ntfstime.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/object_id.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/param.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/realpath.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/reparse.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/runlist.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/security.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/support.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/types.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/unistr.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/volume.h
/usr/local/include/ntfs-3g/xattrs.h
/usr/local/share/man/man8/mkfs.ntfs.8 -> /usr/local/share/man/man8/mkntfs.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/mkntfs.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/mount.lowntfs-3g.8 -> /usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/mount.ntfs-3g.8 -> /usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.probe.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.secaudit.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfs-3g.usermap.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfscat.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsclone.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfscluster.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfscmp.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfscp.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsfix.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsinfo.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfslabel.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsls.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsprogs.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsresize.8
/usr/local/share/man/man8/ntfsundelete.8
/usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.86.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.a
/usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.dylib -> /usr/local/lib/libntfs-3g.86.dylib
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libntfs-3g.pc
$
```

but even after 'brew uninstall...' the directory /usr/local/include/ntfs-3g still exists

Comment: What is the output of `brew link --overwrite --dry-run ntfs-3g`?

Comment: Again.. updated... thanks for helping...

Comment: Could you run `sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local` then try again `brew link --overwrite ntfs-3g`?

Comment: Yeah - I already sudo chmod 777 and re-ran - seemed ok now (I put back 755 and rebooted - now to see if all is ok

Comment: Mounted 3TB WD iBook and all seems fine - read and write. Still curious why /usr/local/include/ntfs-3g was only 755 to me (I only chmod'd on the lower ntfs-3g folder - not the entire /usr/local/ !! ). Perhaps from before I upgraded to El Capitan (10.11)? Still, it's weird

Comment: Arrrggg... now every time I connect the drive, the name increments by one (1) each time.... How do i get it to remount under the old name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `brew link homebrew/fuse/ntfs-3g`.

---

To go further here are the common commands relevant here:

```
brew install <formula>   # install (and link) the formula
brew unlink <formula>    # unlink the formula
brew link <formula>      # link the formula
brew uninstall <formula> # uninstall (and unlink) the formula
```

To understand this you need to know that when Homebrew installs a formula `foo` version `1.2.3`, it installs everything under `/usr/local/Cellar/foo/1.2.3/` then symlinks all binaries in `/usr/local/bin`; all manpages under `/usr/local/share/man`; etc. This means that `/usr/local/bin/something` is *not* a binary but a symlink to the relevant binary (e.g. `/usr/local/Cellar/foo/1.2.3/bin/something`).
Sometimes binaries conflict with each other. For example both `mysql` and `mariadb` provide a `mysql` binary. Homebrew won’t be able to link both at the same time so it allows you to install one; unlink it; then install the other. That way you can have both on your system without conflict.

Comment: Please see my updated question with the results of your suggestion.

Comment: Arrrggg... now every time I connect the drive, the name increments by one (1) each time.... How do i get it to remount under the old name?

Comment: Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ntfs-3g/2017.3.23... 
Error: Could not symlink sbin/mkntfs
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.